# The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods' threw an exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I've got one function app which throws following error when I run it with `azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.3780` `start` command.

```
func start
```

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Test. 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: The type initializer for 
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' 
threw an exception. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: 
The type initializer for 
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethods' threw an exception. 
System.Linq: Sequence contains more than one matching element.
```

**Entrypoint**

```cs
private readonly IRepository _repository;

[FunctionName("Test")]
        public async Task TestAsync(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(
                "%topic%",
                "%subscription%",
                Connection = "connectionString")]
            Message message)
    {
        var result = await _repository.ToListAsync();
    }
```

**It works fine when function app is launched from Visual Studio.**

I thought I could get rid of that by directly referencing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in function app csproj.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**FunctionApp.csproj**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" 
    Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FirstLib\FirstLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**FirstLib.csproj**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SecondLib\SecondLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**SecondLib.csproj**

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="3.1.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Visual Studio version**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.10.4
```

Comment: Have you tried this in Console app? Looks like something wrong with library versions.

Comment: Install the [latest version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/tag/4.0.3893) of core tools.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem went away when I upgraded `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to `5.0.0` in `SecondLib` dependency.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The `TargetFramework` wasn't touched

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Comment: Thank you ,the same could be done when upgrading form .NET 5 -> .NET 6

Comment: `update-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore` solved it for me